# Hide keyboard when switching tabs in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard, android-tabs

I have created tab strip with custom classes and I am displaying one fragment in each tab. When the keyboard is open and I switch to tab then second fragment is getting called but the keyboard is not hiding.

I am using the code below in onCreateView() in both fragment but it's not working:

```
//To Hide Soft 
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem with using that code in `onCreateView()` is the fragment initialized within the tabs are created whenever the tabs are created in the parent fragment / activity. I did some investigating with the behavior of fragments within tabs and realised you'd have the same problem overriding many of the lifecycle methods such as `onViewCreated()`, `onResume()`, etc.

I found that the best solution to this problem is to override `setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)` in the fragment where you want the keyboard to be hidden. This method is called any time the visibility of a fragment changes.

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            try {
                InputMethodManager mImm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                mImm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
                mImm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "setUserVisibleHint: ", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks,this worked for me in tab fragments when switching

Comment: _setUserVisibleHint()_ has been deprecated for a while now. You may want to simply move the logic into _onResume()_ instead

Answer (score 3):

Use this class to hide and show keyboard at runtime. Try to call the method on your onTabChangedListener. Hope it helps.

```
public class KeyBoardHandler {

    public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    public static void showSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers a question not asked.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in onDestroy method of fragment.

```
try {
        InputMethodManager mImm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mImm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mView.getWindowToken(), 0);
        mImm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

Interface:
ICallBacks

```
public interface ICallBacks {
  public void isChanged();
}
```

In your activity define on variable like

```
public ICallBacks mCallbacks;
```

In OnPageChangeListener

```
 @Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {


    if (mCallbacks != null)
        mCallbacks.isChanged();
}
```

In your fragment you need to implement with ICallBacks interface

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (activity != null) {
        ((PagerActivity) getActivity()).mCallbacks = this;
    }

}
@Override
public void isChanged() {

    if (isVisible())
        hideKeyboard();
}

    private void hideKeyboard() {
      InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
      View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
      if (view != null) {
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried here:public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_route_audit, container, false);
        hideKeyboard(rootView);

        ((SideDrawerActivity)getActivity()).setTitle("Route Audit");
        BindView(rootView);

        return rootView;
    }

Comment: @user3138859 - try to hide the keyboard in onDestroyView of every fragment

Comment: is the keyboard is enabled when the fragment is Visible?

Comment: @user3138859 -when the keyboard is visible in ur situation?

Comment: when i enter value in edittext then keyboard is open... and then suppose I move to another tab ...second fragment is being called.. even then keyboard is still opened

Comment: are you using view pager?

Comment: i think you need to implement OnPageChangeListener in onPageScrolled you need to communicate with your fagment using with one interface in that method you nedd to call hide key board .its working for me if you are intrested then i will be post that code

Answer (score 0):

If you come here like me in 2022 you should be using `ViewPager2` and `onResume` and `onPause` methods to know which fragment is currently visible.

I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57885849/in-androidx-fragment-app-fragment-setuservisiblehint-is-deprecated-and-not-exec) and I got to it thanks to the IDE telling me a method used in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43890114/9921564) answer is deprecated, so thanks for the answer!

I am still trying to figure out how to not show it in the first place, but I guess that's because I selected something on the other tab which for some reason gets loaded first...