# in androidx.fragment.app.Fragment，setUserVisibleHint（）is Deprecated，and not executed,why？

Tags: android, androidx

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
        isVisible = true;
        onVisible();
    } else {
        isVisible = false;
        onInVisible();
    }
}
```

I found that this part of the code is not executed.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

They just changed API in Fragments.

If you use this method to limit fragments lifecycle:

> You can now set a max Lifecycle state for a Fragment by calling
> setMaxLifecycle() on a FragmentTransaction. This replaces the now
> deprecated setUserVisibleHint().

Source: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.1.0-alpha07 .

If you need this method because you try to detect which fragment is currently visible in `ViewPager`. You can now just use `onResume` and `onPause` methods instead but before that you should change default behaviour in `FragmentPagerAdapter` constructor.

Like this:

```
FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT)
```

Edit:
Because `FragmentPagerAdapter` is deprecated as well it is better to use [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2) now.
In case of `ViewPager2` it is default behaviour and we can use `onResume` and `onPause` methods to know which fragment is currently visible.

Comment: And what if fragment isn't a part of ViewPager? I need to notify other classes that fragment show up or disappear on screen. Any solution for that?

Comment: @LunaVulpo any lead ?

Comment: @Rajat Sangrame: In one activity I have playback fragment and over them controls fragment and settings fragment. I need to know if controls fragment is still visible and base on that adjust settings fragment. UX requirements.

Comment: I have 3 fragments always in memory. So when the activity is resumed, the fragments' onResume is also called. I want to do analytics for the count metric how many times a fragment is actually shown to the user. For that, I need to know how many times a fragment is actually switched to and not how many times it was resumed.

Comment: @Can I this approach with `FragmentStateAdapter`?

Comment: what about viewpager2 and FragmentStateAdapter ? is there a solution?

Comment: FragmentPagerAdapter is also deprecated. That is just crazy, omg GOOGLE.

Answer (score 17):

Now in `AndroidX` method `setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)` is deprecated and if you take a look into documentation, it says:

> You can now set a max `Lifecycle` state for a Fragment by calling
>   `setMaxLifecycle()` on a `FragmentTransaction`. This replaces the now
>   deprecated `setUserVisibleHint()`. `FragmentPagerAdapter` and
>   `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` have a new constructor that allows you to
>   switch to the new behavior.

So basically when you use this approach in `FragmentTransaction`:

```
.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .setMaxLifecycle(fragment, Lifecycle.State.STARTED);
```

would be equivalent to `setUserVisibleHint(false)` and:

```
.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .setMaxLifecycle(fragment, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);
```

would be equivalent to: `setUserVisibleHint(true)`

Answer (score 13):

**This answer assumes that you are using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`**

On the new version of `androidx.fragment` (from 1.1.0+), `Fragment.setUserVisibleHint` will still get called if your `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is using the old behavior, specified by `BEHAVIOR_SET_USER_VISIBLE_HINT`.

If you have constructed your `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and passed `BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT`, then `Fragment.setUserVisibleHint` will no longer be called inside `FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem`.

**NOTE:** you can still call the deprecated `Fragment.getUserVisibleHint` if you have specified `BEHAVIOR_SET_USER_VISIBLE_HINT` in your `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, but be advised that it will return `true` even though `Fragment.isResumed()` will return false.

---

The `androidx` project is open source. By taking a look at the latest code on master, you can see that an `if` has been added around `setUserVisibleHint` inside `instantiateItem`: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/fragment/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java#195

- **TL;DR:**

**1.0.x:**

```
fragment.setMenuVisibility(false);
fragment.setUserVisibleHint(false);
```

**1.1.0+:**

```
fragment.setMenuVisibility(false);
if (mBehavior == BEHAVIOR_SET_USER_VISIBLE_HINT) {
    fragment.setUserVisibleHint(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**There is a new method in fragment itself**

> Return true if the fragment is in the resumed state. This is true for the duration of onResume() and onPause() as well.

`package androidx.fragment.app;`

```
final public boolean isResumed() {
   return mState >= RESUMED;
}
```

You can call this method by typing:

```
if (isResumed) {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Works well with FragmentStatePager

Answer (score 1):

A simple explanation for those who don't understand.

in your ViewPagerAdapter must be like this, constructor send super

```
super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
```

The whole code looks like this.

```
private static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> fragmentTitle = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        fragments.add(fragment);
        fragmentTitle.add(title);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentTitle.get(position);
    }

}
```

In this way, the onresume method in the fragment will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `FragmentStateAdapter`, you should use `registerFragmentTransactionCallback` method to check lifecycle of a Fragment's interaction with `ViewPager2`.

I need to have back stack of ViewPager2 as i [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62629094/how-to-navigate-back-from-fragments-inside-navhostfragment-of-viewpager2), and implementation is

```
init {
    // Add a FragmentTransactionCallback to handle changing
    // the primary navigation fragment
    registerFragmentTransactionCallback(object : FragmentTransactionCallback() {

        override fun onFragmentMaxLifecyclePreUpdated(
            fragment: Fragment,
            maxLifecycleState: Lifecycle.State
        ) = if (maxLifecycleState == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {

            // This fragment is becoming the active Fragment - set it to
            // the primary navigation fragment in the OnPostEventListener
            OnPostEventListener {
                fragment.parentFragmentManager.commitNow {
                    setPrimaryNavigationFragment(fragment)
                }
            }

        } else {
            super.onFragmentMaxLifecyclePreUpdated(fragment, maxLifecycleState)
        }
    })
}
```

My question was to set back stack for fragments of ViewPager2 with each it's own back stack only when they are visible since having OnBackPressed on every fragment caused undesired pop stack, you can modify or use other methods of `FragmentTransactionCallback`.

However, i don't know it's false positive or not but Leak Canary shows `FragmentMaxLifeCycleEnforcer` instance leaking sometimes, so if you face a problem like this, you might need to unregister `FragmentTransactionCallback` in `onPause` or other relevant method

Answer (score 0):

I use the below in kotlin to handle code when a fragment is visible to the user.

```
Class ZeroFragment : Fragment() {

//Below onResume executed when this fragment is displayed to the user.
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        readData()
    }
}
```