# setUserVisibleHint() is Deprecated in androidx.fragment.app.Fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, deprecated, setuservisiblehint

`androidx.fragment.app.Fragment's setUserVisibleHint（）`is Deprecated, so how can I know which `fragment` is visible to user in `Viewpager2`'s `FragmentStateAdapter`??

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57885849/in-androidx-fragment-app-fragment-setuservisiblehint-is-deprecated-and-not-exec

Comment: How can i use this in FragmentStateAdapter?  i use viewPager2

Comment: Only the current fragment is resumed, every other fragment is started