# How can I check which fragment is visible in Tabbed Layout?

Tags: android

I'm very new to Android Developing.
I try to use "tabbed activity" from Android Studio templates.
I added two classes (Frag1 and Frag2)

```
public class Frag2 extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2_layout,container,false);
}
```

}

And changed the "SectionsPagerAdapter.java" code like that:

```
public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            fragment = new Frag1();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Frag2();
            break;
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

How can I check which fragment is visible on my phone screen?
Thank you in advance!

@EDIT

According to Nizar answer (thanks a lot Nizar!)i add this:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser == true){
        Log.i("xxx", "setUserVisibleHint VISIBLE");
    }else {
        Log.i("xxx", "setUserVisibleHint INVISIBLE");
    }


}
```

This definitely works great, but i receive report:
Override deprecated method in 'androidx.fragment.app.Fragment'
'setUserVisibleHint(boolean) is deprecated..

Is this a problem ?

Comment: Each fragment has a public method `isVisible()` which returns true if the fragment is currently visible to the user.

Comment: Thank you very much, Nizar!Please, read my edit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in androidx.fragment.app.Fragment，setUserVisibleHint（）is Deprecated，and not executed,why？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57885849/in-androidx-fragment-app-fragment-setuservisiblehint-is-deprecated-and-not-exec)

Comment: Yes.Thanks a lot, Nizar !!