# Different FAB click listener for each different fragment on the Navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, floating-action-button

At current implementation of my app I am using the [Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started). In my main content I have a floating action button for all. And at the same time I have 7 different fragment which are automatically handled by the navigation controller when transition is needed.

```
mAppBarConfiguration =
        new AppBarConfiguration.Builder( navigationDrawerFragmentIds ).setDrawerLayout( drawer ).build();
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController( this, R.id.nav_host_fragment );
```

Till today I used the setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) method to override different behaviour(on click listener) for my single fab in the each different fragment.

Like below

```
// FIXME: 2.11.2019 Fix deprecated methods.
@Override public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint( isVisibleToUser );
    if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()) {
        //Only manually call onResume if fragment is already visible
        //Otherwise allow natural fragment lifecycle to call onResume
        onResume();
    } else {
        // current fragment not visible
        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener( null );
    }
}

@Override public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // FIXME: 2.11.2019 Fix deprecated methods.
    if (!getUserVisibleHint()) {
        return;
    }

    // Set listener for float action button which has been defined in main activity.
    // Here we will override the listener which can be work for our current fragment.
    floatingActionButton = getActivity().findViewById( R.id.fab );
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View view) {
            // do some stuff here.
        }
    } );
}
```

Since setUserVisibleHint is deprecated anymore, I wanted to replace new behaviour instead this method like suggested in the release note.

> Max Lifecycle: You can now set a max Lifecycle state for a Fragment by
>   calling setMaxLifecycle() on a FragmentTransaction. This replaces the
>   now deprecated setUserVisibleHint(). FragmentPagerAdapter and
>   FragmentStatePagerAdapter have a new constructor that allows you to
>   switch to the new behavior.

And also [navigation controller](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/fragment/NavHostFragment) has default FragmentNavigator as I understood but I could not understand is this help to me to set the fragments life cycle or behaviour like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57885849/in-androidx-fragment-app-fragment-setuservisiblehint-is-deprecated-and-not-exec). If I can set the behaviour like mentioned post then I can basically use the onResume and onStart (I assume that will work like this because when I select the BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT then the next fragment will not be initiated. only onCreateView called I assume.)

As I explained above that I am using navigation component to handle transition between my fragments. That is why I do not have any special view pager. But I can still get the information via below code the current destination and callback will handle whenever transition is occured between fragments.

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener( new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination,
                                     @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
        Log.i( TAG, "onDestinationChanged: "  + destination.getLabel());

    }
} );
```

Then on my main activity I can set the different behaviour for my fab for each fragment. Up to now this is okey for me. But I wanted to learn is there any way that I can set the max life cycle of the fragment while I am using the Navigation component ?

Thanks in advance.