# Android Fragment with ViewPager and SectionsPageAdapter method executed on user clicks tab name to display it or swipes to it

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have been trying to determine why the `onPause()` and the `onResume()` methods were not fired when the user switches the the tab to be displayed when using a ViewPager and sectionsPageAdapter.

I assumed that when the user changes the tab being displayed, the `onPause()` or the `onDestroy()` methods would be called. Then, if the user returns to the tab, the `onResume()` method would be called, but it seems it is not the functionality...

is there any way to determine when the user switces a tab and to know to which tab it has been switched? Something like `onFragmentBeingDisplayed()` or similar.

Thanks!

**EDIT: Answer from Suraj Vaishnav**

By editing the constructor from the `FragmentPageAdapter` like this `super(fm, FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);` I could use the desired behaviour on the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because ViewPager loads some fragments on the left side and on the right side of the current fragment. By default, ViewPager loads one on the left side and one on the right side of the fragment. You can change the number via: `viewpager.setOfScreenPageLimit(int);`

What you thinking is working exactly the same way in `androidx's` Fragment. Means `onPause` and `onResume` will call accordingly. So the first suggestion is to use `androix`. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57886441/7682257

For some reason, If you do not want to use `androidx` then in your Fragment, override `setUserVisibleHint` method, which gives you `isVisibleToUser` as a parameter.

Comment: Hi, my fragment class is already extending from the ```Fragment``` class from androidx ```import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;```... and still the onPause and onResume methods are not called when I swipe or click to show the desired tab... could you tell me why?

Comment: You need to use FragmentPagerAdapter with BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT, as mentioned in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57886441/7682257, check it, it will help you surely

Comment: Hi Sujaj! Indeed it worked! thank you very much. I edited the constructor so it used now: ```super(fm, FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);``` and it worked as expected!

Nevertheless, I realized that the ```FragmentPageAdapter```got deprecated... (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentPagerAdapter) I will have to give a look to how to use the new implementation.

Anyway, thanks for your fast response and your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Androidx version of Viewpager to get the use of the `BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT` behavior to fire `onResume` only on the displayed Fragment then you can instead add an [addOnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager/widget/ViewPager#addOnPageChangeListener(androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener))

You can use the [ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener](http://ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener) or your own implementation of the `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` interface.

This `PageChangeListener` has a `onPageSelected` method with gets called with the position selected.

While I have given links to the Androidx Documentation this also works in earlier support libraries, just Google have removed the docs for it as they want you to use Androidx

Note this `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` `onPageSelected` fires at a slightly different time to `onResume` with `BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT`. It fires when about 50% of the new tab is swiped on to the screen when `onResume` fires when 100% of the new tab is on screen.

Comment: Hi, the thing is that I am already using the androidx implementation... I already tried to use the ```addOnPageChangeListener``` approach, but I find it not as clean as it would be using the onPause and onResume methods of each of the fragments... that is the reason why I was asking. Do you know why if I am using the AndroidX it is not working?

Comment: As you worked out you were not creating the adapter with the right flags but without code examples in the question it was impossible to work this out.