# ViewPager swallows onBackPressed so FragmentContainerView cannot be navigated

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

So I have an app that has the following layout

`Activity` -> `ViewPager` -> `FragmentA` -> `FragmentContainerView` -> `FragmentB`

`FragmentContainerView` contains a `NavHostFragment`, which displays `FragmentB` using a `nav_graph`. There is a button in `FragmentB` that navigates to a new instance of `FragmentB`. So the Nav graph is basically just one fragment that has a link to itself.

Now if I have the `FragmentContainerView` directly in my activity, this works fine. However, if I put the `FragmentContainerView` inside another fragment inside a `ViewPager`, the back button no longer allows me to navigate the `FragmentB` navgraph.

I am using `app:defaultNavHost="true"` on the `FragmentContainerView`, but it doesnt help.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, and what could I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Fragment Manager guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager#considerations):

> Consider the navigation structure as a series of layers, with the activity as the outermost layer, wrapping each layer of child fragments underneath. Each layer must have a single primary navigation fragment. When the Back event occurs, the innermost layer controls navigation behavior. Once the innermost layer has no more fragment transactions from which to pop back, control returns to the next layer out, and this process repeats until you reach the activity.

So while `app:defaultNavHost="true"` is setting the `NavHostFragment` inside your `FragmentA` as the primary navigation fragment in its layer (the `childFragmentManager` layer of `FragmentA`), `FragmentA` must **also** be set as the primary navigation fragment in order for any system back button events to make it to `FragmentA` at all.

That same page brings up how to do that:

> To define the primary navigation fragment inside of a fragment transaction, call the [`setPrimaryNavigationFragment()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#setPrimaryNavigationFragment(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)) method on the transaction, passing in the instance of the fragment whose `childFragmentManager` should have primary control.

While `ViewPager2` has APIs to [allow you to set the primary navigation fragment to the current page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62629996/1676363), ViewPager1 has no such API (one of the many reasons why you should absolutely move to ViewPager2).

As a workaround for this in ViewPager1, `FragmentA` could set itself as the primary navigation fragment in `onResume()`:

```
public fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    parentFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .setPrimaryNavigationFragment(this)
        .commit()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually use ViewPager2.. just forgot to mention it because i didn't remember there were 2 of them. However, I cant get any of the code in your link to work.. for some reason none of the functions or types youre using are defined inside my adapter.. I'm inheriting `FragmentStateAdapter`, and for example `registerFragmentTransactionCallback()` is an unresolved reference

Comment: Are you using [ViewPager2 `1.1.0-alpha01`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2#1.1.0-alpha01) as specifically mentioned in that answer?

Comment: nope, seems like that was the issue! Thanks again.